# Assign a canvas element to the img.src

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This works

```
img.src = "assets/img.png";
img.addEventListener('load', function () {
   textureContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   texture.update();
});
```

Now how is it possible to use a canvas element that is already on the page to in to this piece of code. Some thing like this.

```
var img = document.getElementById("canvas1");
textureContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
texture.update();
```

I am looking for a pure javascript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method [Canvas#toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method

> The HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() method returns a data URI containing a representation of the image in the format specified by the type parameter (defaults to PNG). The returned image is in a resolution of 96 dpi.

```
img.src = document.getElementById("canvas1").toDataURL();
```

Working Example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const img_from_canvas = document.getElementById("img_from_canvas");

const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.rect(10, 10, 150, 100);
context.fill();
img_from_canvas.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

```html
<p>canvas</p>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p>image from canvas</p>
<img id="img_from_canvas"/>
```